# Doctrine 2.5 GUID field default value

Tags: doctrine-orm, default, default-value, doctrine-orm-postgres

I am trying to set a default value for an UUID type field

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="uuid", type="guid", options={"default"="uuid_generate_v4()"})
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
 */
private $uuid;
```

However this sets executes

`ALTER TABLE store ALTER uuid SET DEFAULT 'uuid_generate_v4()';`

and takes it as text. How do I define a DB function as default in doctrine annotations?

Answer (score 3):

On creation table you can use this annotation

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="uuid", type="guid", columnDefinition="DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()", options={"comment"="Column Comment Here"})
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
 */
private $uuid;
```

The **ColumnDefinition** append the content to DDL [see Doctrine Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#column)

The SQL output for this config is

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4();
COMMENT ON COLUMN table_name.uuid IS 'Column Comment Here';
```

These annotation does nothing on CHANGE COLUMN. Only works on ADD COLUMN generated SQL. You must recreate the column or change your table by hand.

> **IMPORTANT NOTE:**
>   For those that looking for create [UUID Column Type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html) in PostgreSQL, keep in mind that you need to enable some Extension to use functions that create uuid-hashes.

In the example, ***uuid_generate_v4()*** is derived from [UUID-OSSP](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/uuid-ossp.html) and older versions of PostgreSQL don't support it.
Instead UUID-OSSP you can use ***gen_random_uuid()*** function from [PGCRYPTO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html). The UUID resultant is the same version (v4). Again, older versions doesn't support it.

Just remember to Install the Extension with [Create Extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html).

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"; // OR
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "pgcrypto";
```

> **ANOTHER IMPORTANT NOTE:** In some PostgreSQL installations (like CentOS), extensions are not included by default. You must install them.

For CentOS/RHEL you need to install **postgresql-contrib**. Pay attention to the version of your PostgreSQL. I.e. for version 9.5 you must use **postgresql95-contrib**

#### My Privileges are weak

There's a trick to create uuid hashes without extensions. Just use the instruction above.

```
uuid_in(md5(random()::text || clock_timestamp()::text)::cstring);
```

If your version suport ::UUID casting, use

```
md5(random()::text || clock_timestamp()::text)::uuid
```